# Redirect to error page ReactJS and react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, react-dom

I'm trying to send the user to a generic error page when the App breaks, thing is I'm trying with the [ErrorBoundary](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) method and then rendering out the Redirect;

```
export default class ErrorBoundary extends Component {
    state = { has_error: false }

    componentDidCatch(error, info)
        this.setState({ has_error: true });
    }


    render() {
        if (this.state.has_error)
            return <Redirect to="/somewhere/else" />
        }
        return this.props.children;
    }
};
```

And then using the ErrorBoundary to wrap all the routes and sub components inside the Router

```
<Router history={history}>
    <ErrorBoundary>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route
                path="/createManager/:managerId"
                component={CreateManager}
            />
            <Route path="/login" component={LoginComp} />
            <Route path="/test" component={Test} />
            <Route path="/register" component={RegisterAccount} />
            <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
    </ErrorBoundary>
</Router>
```

The componentDidCatch is never triggered, thus, never leaving the current error page, neither in the dev nor prod version. How can I send the user to a X route when the App breaks or tries to throw an error?

In order to trigger an error, I leave one Component with an empty prop, and later on click trying to use the function that should be passed in the prop.

Comment: what exactly isn't working?

Comment: The `componentDidCatch` is never triggered, thus, never leaving the current error page

Comment: Where have you defined `ErrorBoundary` component

Comment: can you share the code that throws the error as well?

Comment: Sorry, made an small edit, since I had copy pasted from another component I kept the class name but it doesn't affect since it's the default export and the nave is given when importing in the router comp `import ErrorBoundary from "./ErrorBoundary";`

Comment: In order to throw an error, I'm on purpose, leaving a prop empty and later call that empty prop as a callback of an interaction

Comment: i would not go with setting the state inside the render `this.setState({ has_error: false });`

Comment: I've just noticed that indeed that is unnecessary since after I tried with the react dev tools, to change the has_error to true, the change in the routing makes the ErrorBoundary comp to set back the has_error to false, will remove it from the question and my own code

Comment: well, without seeing the entire relevant code (including the error) it's hard to guess.

Comment: The matter is, this should be a generic error handling, so whatever it be the use should be redirect to X url path where the router will show them the "Oops, thing didn't work"

Comment: @NicolasM.Pardo But not all errors are triggering the `componentDidCatch`. errors that caused by event handlers or ajax requests for example, won't trigger it. this is the reason i asked to see where are you having the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`componentDidCatch` only triggers if the **error** is **thrown** inside the **render** method.

The reason why your `componentDidCatch` is not triggered is because **events** like `onClick` is not in the `render` lifecycle. So `componentDidCatch` won't be able to catch this kind of error.

One way to test out the your `componentDidCatch` is throwing an error inside the `render` method.

For errors outside of the render method you have to be careful and add try/catches in places you think might have errors in your action handlers.

Also a good way to prevent undefined onClick is to add `flow` or `typescript`.

https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html#component-stack-traces

> React 16 prints all errors that occurred during `rendering` to the console in development, even if the application accidentally swallows them. In addition to the error message and the JavaScript stack, it also provides component stack traces. Now you can see where exactly in the component tree the failure has happened:

Comment: exactly. but with no code it's hard to guess this is the issue.